# Промежуточное API

Tags: php, api, клиент-сервер

Есть API сайта, но API привязано к IP адресу клиента. А так как для сайта разрабатывает мобильное приложение (где у клиентов будут разные IP), то нужно сделать промежуточный сервер, который будет обращаться к API, а клиент будет к промежуточному серверу.
Как это можно сделать? Может быть есть какие-то готовые решения?

Comment: Странно, а почему бы не привязать API  к адресу сервера, чтобы избежать проблем при разработке "дополнительного сервера" для мобильных приложений?

Comment: Ну получается так и будет, сейчас привязан к адресу мобильного разработчика, в последствии когда будет готов промежуточный сервер апи будет к его адресу привязано.